# Successful deployment but no debugging when deploying files to Hololens via vs

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens

I am working on Hololens2 using Unity. I use unity build and deploy the program to Hololens using Visual-Studio.

Initially it has been successful, but recently I have run into a problem. At the end of the deployment, the output of Visual-Studio lists my "build" as successful and my "deploy" as successful. But at the same time a pop-up appears telling me that

> "Unable to start debugging, operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80070057"

[image]

How can I solve this problem? I can't find any information on the web about this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: before deploying have you tried manually uninstall an existing build from the device first? I had this kind of issue but not sure how exactly it was fixed in the end I'm afraid

Comment: Please refer to the note in [Using Visual Studio to deploy and debug - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-visual-studio?tabs=hl2#:~:text=If%20the%20errors,Unknown%20error%3A%200x80070057%22), try to rename the package or uninstall the application.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I tried all the methods you all described without success. Eventually I changed the version of MRTK from 1.6.0 to 1.5.1 solved the problem.